# Is it safe to cascade constructors in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, multiple-constructors

I want to do the following:

```
// I want to do this! :D

- (instancetype) init
{
    return [self initWithVal1:[NSDecimalNumber zero] val2:MyEnumDefault];
}

- (instancetype) initWithVal1:(NSDecimalNumber*)val1 val2:(MyEnum)val2
{
    return [self initWithVal1:val1 val2:val2 val3:12];
}

- (instancetype) initWithVal1:(NSDecimalNumber*)val1 val2:(MyEnum)val2 val3:(NSInteger)val3
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _prop1 = val1;
        _prop2 = val2;
        _prop3 = val3;
    }
    return self;
}
```

But I know that when I call `[self initWithVal1:[NSDecimalNumber zero]`, `self` has not yet been initialized. However, I've seen examples around the itnernet that show this in examples. **Is this safe, or do I have to initialize them all each time like below?**

```
// I don't want to do this... :(

- (instancetype) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _prop1 = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
        _prop2 = MyEnumDefault;
        _prop3 = 12;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithVal1:(NSDecimalNumber*)val1 val2:(MyEnum)val2
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _prop1 = val1;
        _prop2 = val2;
        _prop3 = 12;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithVal1:(NSDecimalNumber*)val1 val2:(MyEnum)val2 val3:(NSInteger)val3
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _prop1 = val1;
        _prop2 = val2;
        _prop3 = val3;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I don't like that approach, since it duplicates code, like `_prop3 = 12`, which leads to potential discrepancies if the code must be changed later.

Comment: "But I know that when I call [self initWithVal1:[NSDecimalNumber zero], self has not yet been initialized." – yeah, that's why you call its initializer. what's the problem? and yes, it's generally recommended that you re-use initializers' code and only have actual initialization in one of them (there's even a name for that one, it's called the "designated initializer").

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant the problem would be that I'm sending a message to an object that has not yet been initialized? I'm trying to do the designated initializer pattern with the first snippet.

Comment: By that logic you couldn't *ever* initialize *any* object at all. Because then you'd have a circular self-dependency (you could only initialize an initialized object, but you wouldn't have one.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Right... see,  I'm used to using Java's `this(x, y, z)` style cascading constructors, and I'd like to use this in Objective C. **Essentially, I just want to know if the first snippet is safe, and if not, what is safe that would accomplish the same thing?**

Comment: I've already answered that part… it's not only safe, it's recommended.

Comment: The first set of code is just fine. It is correct and typical.

Comment: I don't understand Objective-C, then. I thought that in my first snippet's `init`, `self` is `nil`?

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero no, it isn't. If it was `nil`, how could you possibly dereference it (e.g. when setting its instance variables) in *any* initializer? Anyway, your init method wouldn't be even *called* if it was sent to a `nil` object – the Objective-C messaging system silently returns `0` for any message sent to `nil`.

Comment: It can't be `nil`. You called `alloc` first and if `self` was `nil`, then how would you have called the `init` method to begin with?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant because the first thing I do in other initializers is `self = [super init]`?

Comment: @rmaddy oh yes, that's right. I forgot that about `alloc`, coming from the Java world. Thanks

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero no, because execution doesn't even reach the initializer if the object on which you call it is `nil`.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero if you have an incorrect assumption and I correct you, is that bad? I have already explained the actual reason why `self` cannot possibly be `nil` at the point you asked about. You made an assumption about the cause of it which was wrong, to which my response was a back-reference to my earlier explanation of why it was so.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant perhaps it's your wording, then. The way I put it in my answer below is how I understand it, but your explanations... I dunno, I just can't really understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

**It's safe** because `self` has already been allocated (with `alloc`) by the time its `init` is called. So, methods can be called on it, but its objects are just all not-yet-allocated.